# Waiting for an Event to Complete

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, pivotitem

In Pivot control all Pivot items content is loading at a time in WindowsPhone 7.1 I am developing Cross Platform application.

**Issue:**
In my application each Pivot Item having WebBrowser control. When loading all Pivot Item's Content at a time `java script calls are conflicted`.

**Requirement:** 
If Pivot Control having 4 Pivot Items like item1, item2, item3 and item4, then `load item2 after the content of item1 load finished`.

**EDIT 1:** I have tried the following code http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/synchronization-events-and-wait-handles-in-C-Sharp/

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
foreach (PivotDetails pivotdetails in pivtdetailslist)
{                   
     PivotItem pivotitem = new PivotItem();
     pivotitem.Header = pivotdetails.header;
     WebBrowserControl browsercontrol = new WebBrowserControl(this);
     browsercontrol.Navigate(pivotdetails.url);
     pivotitem.Content = browsercontrol;
     mre.Reset();
     myPivot.Items.Add(pivotitem);
     mre.WaitOne();
}

private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  mre.Set();
}
```

**EDIT1 Issue:** Waiting screen only displaying not able to see Design page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following code for "Wait to complete the event"

```
foreach (PivotDetails pivotdetails in pivtdetailslist)
{                   
     PivotItem pivotitem = new PivotItem();
     pivotitem.Header = pivotdetails.header;
     WebBrowserControl browsercontrol = new WebBrowserControl(this);    
     pivotitem.Content = browsercontrol;
     mre.Reset();
     myPivot.Items.Add(pivotitem);
     mre.WaitOne();
}

private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  myPivot.isHitTestVisible = true;
}

private void myPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
            Pivot pivot = sender as Pivot;
            PivotItem  currentPivot= pivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem;
            if (currentPivot.Content is WebBrowserControl)
            {
               WebBrowserControl bc = currentPivot.Content as WebBrowserControl;
                if (bc.getWebView().Source == null)
                {                    
                    bc.Navigate(pivtdetailslist[pivot.SelectedIndex].url);
                    bc.getWebView().LoadCompleted += new System.Windows.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_LoadCompleted);
                    myPivot.IsHitTestVisible = false;
                }
            }
}
```